# Wix Prerequisite check for IIS8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2 fails

Tags: wix, wix3.8

Even though I have removed Web Server (IIS) roles and features on Windows Server 2012 R2 using Server Manager, my Wix installer prerequisite check says IIS is installed.

I am using following registry keys for prerequisite check

```
<Property Id="P_IISVERSIONMAJOR">
  <RegistrySearch Id="SearchIISMajor" Type="raw"
      Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp" Name="MajorVersion"  Win64="yes" />
</Property>

<Property Id="P_IISVERSIONMINOR">
  <RegistrySearch Id="SearchIISMinor" Type="raw"
      Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp" Name="MinorVersion"  Win64="yes" />
</Property>
```

Are there any keys or something to indicate that IIS needs to be added as a Role (enabled/registered) using Server Manager ?

Any help would be highly appreciated as I am working on a release bug.

Thanks

Edited:

My requirement is to detect if IIS is installed or not. But on Windows Server 2012 R2 by default IIS is available and the below key is always present. 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\InetStp 
Installer shows the prerequisite dialog when all or some of the prerequisites are found missing on the target machine. 
So when user removes Web Server (IIS) Role/Feature from Server manager I need to show that IIS is not installed in prerequisite dialog.For the same I need some way which indicates that IIS is not installed.

Probably my first question was not clear, so tried to put my requirement in detail now and hope its not confusing. Kindly feel free to clarify.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Discover Installed Components](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/discover-installed-components), you should check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\InetStp\Components\` and look for:

```
Display Name            Registry Key
====================================
Web Server              W3SVC
```

From the page:

> ... we are publishing a list of registry keys that show whether any
>   given IIS module has been installed. Use these registry keys to
>   programmatically check on IIS components. If a component has been
>   installed, the registry key has a DWORD value of 00000001. If a
>   component has never been installed or has been uninstalled, the
>   registry key does not exist.

There's probably 20 or 30 components listed on the IIS.net page.

Comment: Thank you! I have indeed used the same key to put checks and conditions for IIS prerequisites. Thanks again.